# I made a character in blender, but I do not know how to import it into Roblox Studio?

Tags: import, lua, blender, roblox

I made a character in blender and i am trying to import the character into roblox studio as a humanoid character. I have looked it up on google but only found how to export characters from roblox studio into blender.

Comment: Does this help: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Mesh-Parts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You shouldn't post non-programming questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you meant:

- If you export your blender file- save it where you like - Make sure it has saved as ***'obj' it might say 'wavefront'***.
- Then if you go to roblox create a meshpart. Right click and search ***meshpart***.
- Then go into the ***meshpart properties at 'MeshID'*** click the little folder icon and find your originally saved obj blender file and click open.